# Get values of GWT Selected checkbox in Celltable

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

In a GWT celltable I have many rows associated with CheckboxCell.I need to know only the values of the selected checkboxes on a particular event.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use SingleSelectionModel or MultiSelectionModel with ProvidesKey implementation (to return unique keys)

```
SelectionModel selectionModel = new MuliSelectionModel<T>(new ProvidesKey><T>() {
    @Override
    public Object getKey(T item) {
        // return unique key here
    }
});
```

then you assign it to celltable

```
table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
```

then you can simply invoke selectionModel.getSelectecSet() and it will return Set of objects which are selected in table.

```
Set<T> selectedObjects = selectionModel.getSelectedSet();
```

HTH